# Oracle. Как объединить несколько значений без повторений в колонке?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

```
SELECT a.first_name || ' ' || b.first_name, b.job_id, a.salary
FROM employees a, employees b
WHERE a.salary = b.salary AND a.job_id = b.job_id AND a.employee_id < b.employee_id;
```

Результат:

```
James Joshua    ST_CLERK    2500
Joshua Peter    ST_CLERK    2500
James Peter     ST_CLERK    2500
```

Нужно:

```
James, Joshua, Peter    ST_CLERK    2500
```

Как можно этого добиться ?

Comment: `distinct` исключет дубли

Comment: Все равно не выводит список работников в одной строке, выводит в разных. Запрос должен вывести: Список сотрудников имеющих одинаковый оклад и работающих на одном предприятии. Если работников всего два, то тут понятно как, а если три, то как сделать это в виде одной строке ?

Comment: И где в условиях задачи сказано, что строка должна быть всего одна ? В любом случае в строке невозможно сделать динамическое количество колонок. Так что в одной строке можно выдавать только в одной колонке, например через запятую. Для этого служит функция listagg

Comment: Начал писать ответ, но вспомнил, что вы редко принимаете ответы, на комментарии не отвечаете. Желание отвечать пропало, делайте сами.